# Get document libraries in SharePoint WebSite

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I need to use sharepoint client api in my project and list documents in folders that uploaded to sharepoint. My folders are under the link "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/blsmtekn/dyncrm/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

```
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/"))
        {   
            string userName = "username";
            string password = "password";

            SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
            password.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);

            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);

            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("/Shared Documents/");
            CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
            caml.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                <Query>
                                </Query>
                            </View>";
            caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/blsmtekn/dyncrm/";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(caml);
            ctx.Load(listItems);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

But I'm getting error like “List…does not exist at site with URL”. How can I get list of folders and files under that folders recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head I'm seeing a few mistakes: Your code states, that the name of your library is `/Shared Documents/`, while the name most likely is `Shared Documents`.

Please fix the name of your `GetByTitle()` call:

```
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
```

The second error is, that the url to your site collection is wrong. It should be

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/blsmtekn/dyncrm/")
```

Additionally you can remove `caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/blsmtekn/dyncrm/";` since that is wrong.

All in all your code should look like this:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/blsmtekn/dyncrm/"))
{   
    string userName = "username";
    string password = "password";

    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    password.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);

    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);

    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
    CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
    caml.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                        <Query>
                        </Query>
                    </View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(caml);
    ctx.Load(listItems);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i'm getting same error after your changes.

Comment: I checked my Lists by Web.Lists method and i saw that my files are under "Belgeler" list. I have difficulty to understand sharepoint api and folder structure.

Comment: 1. WebApplication (`SPWebApplication`), 2. SiteCollection (`SPSite`), 3. Site (`SPWeb`), 4. List (`SPList`), 5. ListItem (`SPListItem`). The property ` caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl` only refers to subfolders in your `SPList`. 
The above is a rough hierachy of parent and child relations in SharePoint. Its the same for every SharePoint version.